# Safari Browser Leaves Query String

Tags: javascript

Safari Browser leaves query string (?) in the link when using this approach. Is there anyway to force the browser to also remove the query string? It's not an issue with Firefox or Chrome. I just checked IE and it's the same as issue as with Safari.

```js
$("a")[0].search = "";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com/?title=dog">The Link</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uSrmg/1/[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split on the question mark and take the first half:

```
$("a")[0].href = $("a")[0].href.split('?').shift()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uSrmg/107/

Comment: you sir are a genius! I never thought about using .shift()

Comment: I'm no super genius...or are I? ;) glad to help

Comment: May I ask one more question? What if I use this approach this.search = "";  I observed it suffers from the same issue http://jsfiddle.net/uSrmg/108/

Comment: @Evan, `this` and `$("a")[0]` are really equivalent, so the problem will persist in safari unless you physically remove the `?` from the href